# iOS app to track (not buy or sell) stocks, that can send me price alerts

Tags: ios, iphone-app, finance

I'm looking for an iOS app that can track the value of my stocks. It should do the following:

- show the (time, value) plot of each stock in real time
- alert me if the price of a stocks exceed some upper/lower bounds defined by me
- work on iOS 15.4

It **shouldn't** do the following:

- trade stocks
- require me to sign up to some service

The "don't do" are clearly associated. If an app allowed me to trade stocks, then surely it would require me to create an account somewhere, and I don't want to share my financial data with someone, just to get some price alerts. BTW, note that if the Stocks app allowed setting price alerts, then it would already satisfy all my requirements...

Do you have any suggestions?